# In Gravity, what happened to Ryan’s daughter?

Tags: gravity-movie

Doctor Ryan Stone mentions that she had a daughter named Sarah, and says this when asked on what happened to her.

> **Stone:** *I had a daughter. She was four. She was at school, playing tag. Slipped, hit her head, and that was it. Stupidest thing.*

Did the accident leave Sarah with permanent brain damage, amnesia, or leave her paralysed?

Comment: That kinda implies that she died.

Comment: She definitely died; later on when Dr. Stone says goodbye to Matt she tells him to say "hi" to Sarah for her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [original screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Gravity.html);

> **RYAN:** *I had a daughter.*

Past tense.

Comment: @LouisHolmes - In the original screenplay she fell during a school pool trip. In the actual film she's stated to have just fallen over at school.